# INDIRECT not working with ADDRESS to form range

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

I am trying to create a range which I will eventually want to find the minimum and maximum values with in. I am working with stock price data so the range will vary. I used ADDRESS to identify the beginning and end of the range:

Beginning:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,SPYDATA,0),2)
```

where A2 is the beginning of the range and SPYDATA is the range of dates with open/high/low/close data in the adjacent columns. So the 2 represents the opening price on date A2. This works.

Ending:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(C2,SPYDATA,0),4)
```

where C2 is the end of the range and SPYDATA is the range of dates with open/high/low/close data in the adjacent columns. So the 4 represents the opening price on date C2. This works.

The problem comes when I try to concatenate them into a range that I could then use for =MIN and =MAX:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,SPYDATA,0),2) & ":" & ADDRESS(MATCH(C2,SPYDATA,0),4))
```

It worked once and after that when I tried different dates I get #spill error. The same error occurs now when I go back to the original dates.

Thanks

Comment: Your version is trying to "Spill" the results but there is data in the way.  Wrap it in the Min or Max and it will work.

Comment: BTW one can avoid the volatile formulas with: `=MIN(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,SPYDATA,0)):INDEX(D:D,MATCH(C2,SPYDATA,0)))`

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work even when it was wrapped in the Min or Max as per the first comment. But the second idea worked great. Thanks